# amplify api push does not update schema in cloud and reverts locally

Tags: graphql, schema, serverless, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am using a serverless AWS-based architecture in my react app with AppSync, Cognito, and GraphQL. In the past I have been able to update my graphql schema locally and run `amplify api push` and it successfully pushes all of my changes to the cloud.

Recently I have been trying to update the cloud through `amplify api push` as I have in the pass, and the terminal says "All resources are update in the cloud". However, it reverts my schema to the schema version I had from last push. And needless to say, it was not updated in the cloud either.

No error messages are showing in the terminal.

The change I want to make is as follows:

Before-

```
type Topic @model {
  id: ID!
  postID: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

After-

```
type Topic @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Make sure you are editing `schema.graphql` in the `amplify/backend/api` instead of `current-cloud-backend/api` directory

Comment: This always bites me when I do the occasional Amplify project...

Answer (score 0):

did you change parent directory/folder name?
Once i changed my project's parent directory/folder name and amplify push stopped working.
When reverted directory/folder name back to original fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to making sure you are editing the correct `schema.graphql`, ensure that you are in the app's root directory when calling any `amplify` commands like `amplify push` or `amplify pull.` You might be editing a different `schema.graphql` from the one you are pushing.